How handle navigation in Flutter when mix it with native app
I need to migrate a IOS native app to Flutter, but step by step, so I'll start adding Flutter screens to native app. I found a problem with navigation stack. If a push a Flutter app, the IOS appbar reaming visible make looks Flutter view strange. I was able to remove the native app, but then app can not make swipe gesture to remove the Flutter view. Could it be fix in some way?
In addition to this, The Flutter doc isn't clear about how to navigate when you mix Flutter with native. Should I use Flutter Navigator when I'm in Flutter Views o should I delegate to native handle Flutter navigation?
